# JavaScript 2D array push when empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have been trying to create an empty 2d array and trying to push values into it. 
The following code is as follows.

```
// Create an array like [[],[]]
let series = new Array(2).fill([]);
//try to push value into the array in position 0 like [[5],[]]
series[0].push(5); // output here is [[5],[5]]
```

How can I push element to the array at index 0?

There is something I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: can you show what your desired output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fill([])` it creates one array and fills everything with a reference to that one array. You can use something like `map()` or `Array.from()` which will create a new array object with each iteration:

```js
let series =  Array.from({length: 2}, () => []);

series[0].push(5); 
console.log(series)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[...Array(2)].map(a=>[]);` instead.

When you use fill you assign the same object reference to everything

```js
let series = [...Array(2)].map(a=>[]);
series[0].push(5);

console.log(series)
```